# Как подключить докер контейнер puppeteer к контейнеру моего приложения

Tags: docker, puppeteer

У меня есть такое приложение

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    image: app
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php-fpm/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - test-network

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      -  ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - test-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - test-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Мне в этом приложении нужно законектить puppeteer

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserWSEndpoint: `ws://0.0.0.0:3000/`,
      defaultViewport: null, // <= set this to have viewport emulation off
    });
```

puppeteer я беру из этого снимка puppeteer

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 browserless/chrome
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome/#hosting-providers

Я плохо понимаю сеть внутри докера, и я не могу понять следующее:

1)как мне узнать browserWSEndpoint, я понимаю что он 3000 порте но какой у него ip 0.0.0.0 или ip адрес контейнера

2)нужно ли добавлять контейнер  с puppeteer в сеть приложения test-network

3)нужно ли добавлять прокси в приложение для puppeteer

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, извините за кривое объяснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задан маппинг/проброс портов (port mapping) для доступа к контейнеру с хост-машины (в данном случае с вашего ПК), то к контейнеру с хост-машины можно обратиться по адресу 0.0.0.0:3000 или localhost:3000. Маппинг выполняется через  настройку параметра ports в docker-compose или через аргумент --publish (-p) для команды docker run. Например, -p 8080:80 - привязать порт 80 контейнера к порту 8080 хоста ([Published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)).

В текущей конфигурации есть сеть test-network и отдельный контейнер. Нужно обратиться к контейнеру из сети. Для этого надо сначала из сети обратиться к хосту ([I want to connect from a container to a service on the host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)), а с хоста уже к контейнеру. Итог будет выглядеть так: host.docker.internal:3000

Удобнее и правильнее добавить контейнер browserless/chrome в docker-compose в ту же сеть и задать ему имя, например, browserless:

```
browserless:
  image: browserless/chrome:1.50-chrome-stable
  container_name: "browserless"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  networks:
    - test-network
```

Внутри сети действует динамическая генерация ip-адресов, но dns-имя постоянно - это имя контейнера. И адрес для доступа внутри сети будет выглядеть как browserless:3000. Подробнее можно прочитать здесь [Сети Docker](https://habr.com/ru/post/310460/#net)

Дополнительная ссылка с примером для browserless здесь [Using with docker-compose ? #52](https://github.com/browserless/chrome/issues/52), надеюсь, примеры еще рабочие.

Если вопрос из п.3 после выполнения пунктов выше будет актуален, уточните функционал, который нужно настроить.